# Android listview is not working

Tags: android, listview

*Since i am new to android development i want to bind a sample data from array to the list view but i"m getting error in*

```
setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, city));
```

and also some import statements are failed to import in android studio

**mycode** :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String[] city = {
            "Bangalore",
            "Chennai",
            "Mumbai"
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        //Listview adapter
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, city));  
    }
}
```

Comment: setListAdapter is in ListActivity, not in AppCompatActivity. It's probably not even compile?

Comment: import android.widget.ArrayAdapter; delete this line and set Array Adapter which extends BaseAdapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   ListView listView ;
   String[] city = { "Bangalore","Chennai","Mumbai" };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);          
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.yourlistviewid);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, city ); 
    listView.setAdapter(adapter); 
   }

}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer . i"m still in early stage so that i can"t figure out want"s going on there .. anyways thankz it"s working fine now i get it